# Confirmation message with Jqueryui always return true

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I wrote a function named `confirmMessage(msg)` to work with onclick event of links:

```
<a href="delete.php?id=12" onclick="return confirmMessage('Are You REALLY Sure?')">Delete</a>
```

The code of the function is:

```
<script>
    function confirmMessage(msg){
    p = true
    elementHtml = '<div id="ConfirmMessage">'+msg+'</div>';
    $("body").append(elementHtml);
    $("#ConfirmMessage").dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Delete": function() {
        p = true;           
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );

        },
        Cancel: function() {
        p = false;
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );

        }
      }
    }

    );

    return p;

}

    </script>
```

In the function above I set a variable `p` to be case container i.e. true or false and initially I set it to be true. Also, The message element is created on the fly. However, when I click on the delete link, it dose not wait till I decide to delete or cancel and it go to delete.

When I set `p` initially to be false, it does not do anything else closing the dialog what ever the decision.

Where is the mistake in this code?!

Comment: Because it is asynchronous! There is no way to wait for the user to click the buttons before continuing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery dialog asynchronous -- it doesn't block.  The function will go on and return without waiting for a response.  You will need to use the following code:

```
function confirmMessage(msg,goto){
    elementHtml = '<div id="ConfirmMessage">'+msg+'</div>';
    $("body").append(elementHtml);
    $("#ConfirmMessage").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete": function() {   
                 $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                 window.location.href=goto;
             },
             Cancel: function() {
                 $( this ).dialog( "close" );
             },
         },
     });
    return false;
}
```

and:

```
<a href="delete.php?id=12" onclick="return confirmMessage('Are You REALLY Sure?',this.href)">Delete</a>
```

Changing so the return is not what is actually determining what happens.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/NpsYV/).

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution is perfect, However, I used it with more generalization. Instead of regarding fixed goto I used this.

Comment: Yes that is a better solution, I will edit my answer.

Comment: After banging my head for hours, finally found this gem buried under heaps of Google results. Thank god.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is in thinking that the function waits for you to click on one of the buttons before returning. `.dialog()` displays the dialog and returns immediately. Responding to user interactions must be done in callback functions.

Use the `close:` handler to run code when the dialog is closed:

```
$("#ConfirmMessage").dialog({
  resizable: false,
  height:140,
  modal: true,
  close: function() {
    if (p) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
  },
  buttons: {
    "Delete": function() {
    p = true;           
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );

    },
    Cancel: function() {
    p = false;
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );

    }
  }
}

);
```

Comment: I tried your code with replacing `...` by `return true` and `return false` respectively. However, it does not solve the issue too!

Comment: You don't seem to understand asynchronous operations. There's nothing to return to. You need to take action, like submitting or not submitting an AJAX request.

Comment: It's built into the browser, and it's synchronous, it doesn't manipulate the DOM like jQuery UI does.

Answer (score 0):

you "return p" is executed before you are even able to see the modal window. your dialog method is executed asynchronously